# Xamarin Forms ProgressBar Stop

Tags: c#, xamarin, progress-bar, xamarin.forms

What is the best way to stop the progress bar animation in Xamarin Forms? Progress is started with:

```
animProgressBar = async () => { 
 ... 
 await progressBar.ProgressTo (0, 10000, Easing.Linear); 
 ... 
};
```

I would like to stop the animation and restart it. I have tried things like

```
progressBar.AbortAnimation("ProgressTo");
```

without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is possible to cancel `ProgressTo` and I suppose that creating own animation is easiest solution:

```
new Button
{
    Text = "Kick progress bar",
    Command = new Command(() =>
    {
        if (progressBar.AnimationIsRunning("SetProgress"))
        {
            progressBar.AbortAnimation("SetProgress");
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar.Animate("SetProgress",(arg) => { progressBar.Progress = arg; }, 8*60, 8*1000, Easing.Linear);
        }
    })
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That is really cool, thanks. And could you tell me what you used to do the animation? I've seen them around but any hint would be appreciated. Thanks again

Comment: Sure: "Animate", "AnimationIsRunning", and "AbortAnimation" are methods of "AnimationExtensions" class: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.AnimationExtensions/

Comment: Sorry, I mean the visual gif. How did you do that?

Comment: Ok, I just recorder the part of screen via QuickTime and converted the resulting ".mov" to ".gif" using ffmpeg: https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality/556031#556031

Comment: @MikalaiDaronin What is "arg" in this context please?

Comment: @RazvanEmil, animation callback value is from 0 to 1 as far I remember

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest you to set `progressBar.Progress = 0` to reset all progress.
I made quick example:

```
Device.StartTimer(System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), () =>
        {
            myProgressBar.Progress += 0.01;
            if (myProgressBar.Progress > .5)
            {
                myProgressBar.Progress = 0;
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });
```

Comment: Hmmm... thanks but it seems a bit like a hack as the progressbar is meant to be used with 

animProgressBar = async () => {
    ...
    await progressBar.ProgressTo (0, 10000, Easing.Linear);
    ...

   };

anyway to cancel that animation?

Comment: await myProgressBar.ProgressTo(0, 1000, Easing.Linear); First parameter is a value to which progress will be animated and second parameter is responsible for speed of animation. So, to reset progress immediately you could try await myProgressBar.ProgressTo(0, 0, Easing.Linear);

Comment: If the animation is not finished it creates a System.InvalidOperationException "An attempt was made to transition a task to a final state when it had already completed.", because the other animation has not finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `progressBar.AbortAnimation("Progress");`

as it's the actual name of animation in source code.

```
        public Task<bool> ProgressTo(double value, uint length, Easing easing)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            this.Animate("Progress", d => Progress = d, Progress, value, length: length, easing: easing, finished: (d, finished) => tcs.SetResult(finished));

            return tcs.Task;
        }
```

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ProgressBar.cs#L37