# Xamarin C# How to use a cancellation token to stop the progress bar process?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, xamarin

The app records a sound. I am trying to stop the progress bar when the user presses "stop recording" but the progress bar is currently not stopping. Here is what I have tried:

```
private async Task RecordAudio()
        {
            buttonSave.IsEnabled = false;
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            try
            {
                if (!recorder.IsRecording)
                {
                    buttonRecord.IsEnabled = false;
                    buttonPlay.IsEnabled = false;

                    // only if ios
                    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                        DependencyService.Get<IAudioService>().PrepareRecording();


                    var recordTask = await recorder.StartRecording();

                    RunProgressActivity(cts.Token);

                    buttonRecord.Text = "Stop";
                    buttonRecord.IsEnabled = true;

                    // get the recorded file
                    var recordedAudioFile = await recordTask;


                    if (recordedAudioFile != null)
                    {
                        // do something with it
                        buttonSave.IsEnabled = true;
                    }

                    buttonRecord.Text = "Record";
                    buttonPlay.IsEnabled = true;
                }
                else // stop button clicked
                {
                    cts.Cancel(); // here is where i am trying to stop the progress bar

                    buttonRecord.IsEnabled = false;

                    await recorder.StopRecording();

                    buttonSave.IsEnabled = true;                 
                    buttonRecord.IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            cts = null;
        }
```

And the method the method for the progress bar:

```
private async void RunProgressActivity(CancellationToken cancelToken) => await progressBarRecordTime.ProgressTo(1, 20000, Easing.Linear);
```

I know I am missing something, can you please point in the right direction?

Comment: I suspect a cause of your problems is likely down to the fact that you are creating a new token each time the button is pressed and not storing it for use when stopping the recording. Because you are creating a new one the cancellation signal will have zero effect in `RunProgressActivity`

Comment: @Bijington Sounds it could be that reason, ideas on how to fix it? Create the tokensource object as a class member?

Comment: In actual fact it looks like trying to cancel the animation may not strictly be possible. This answer to a very similar question could be your best option:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36184451/32348

Comment: A further question, what value is the `ProgressBar` offering? Are you giving the user a time limit on what can be recorded? If not then perhaps something other than a `ProgressBar` would be better? e.g. something like an `ActivityIndicator`

Comment: @Bijington oh wow, that is an interesting post, exactly what im trying to do, thanks for that I am going to look into it now.

Comment: @Bijington yes there is a time limit in seconds, a fixed length for the audio recordign. And I also want to use that indicator for the playback, for the length of the playback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205004/discussion-between-razvan-emil-and-bijington).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, the CancellationToken may be used to download long file or other operation in background, you want to stop Progressbar, I think it will have some issue.

Here is the article about using CancellationToken:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-an-async-task-or-a-list-of-tasks

I suggest you can follow Bijington's opinion, do like this:

```
 private async void Start_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do other operation
        progressbar1.Animate("SetProgress", (arg) => { progressbar1.Progress = arg; }, 8 * 60, 8 * 1000, Easing.Linear);
     
    }

    private void Stop_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (progressbar1.AnimationIsRunning("SetProgress"))
        {
            progressbar1.AbortAnimation("SetProgress");
        }
    }
```